# OpenTBS multiply variable with other variable inside table

Tags: php, docx, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am trying to use the following functionality:

```
[quote_elements.product.factor;ope=mul:quote_elements.qty]
```

But all I get is always 0.
if I use:

```
[quote_elements.product.factor;ope=mul:4]
```

it works fine and I get 4 times the factor number.
But this is not what I need. I need to multiply dynamically the factor with the quantity. this can be for each row different.

any tips what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Embedded TBS fields does not work in parameter `ope`.
That why the string « quote_elements.qty » is always converted to 0.
Parameter `ope=mul` can work only with fixed values.

In order to solve you problem, you can use a custom [ondata function](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_prm_ondata). It will enable you to add a calculated column in you record before to merge it.

PHP side:

```
function f_my_ondata($BlockName, &$CurrRec, $RecNum) {
  $CurrRec['my_result'] = $CurrRec['product']['factore'] * $CurrRec['qty'];
}
```

Template side :

```
[quote_elements;block=...;ondata=f_my_ondata] // block definition
...
[quote_elements.my_result]
```